# MySQL query select from multiple tables, display all from table1 + some data from table2

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables. I want to print out **all access-lists from table1**, plus the **interface** from table2. But some access-lists don't have an associated interface with the access-list (but I still want to print these access-lists). How do i do this? (I just can't get the desired result result ._.)

table1

```
| id | access-list  | ... 
+----+--------------+ 
| 0  | list_1       | ...
| 1  | list_2       | ...
| 2  | list_3       | ...
| 3  | list_4       | ...
```

table2

```
| id | access-list  | interface |
+----+--------------+-----------+
| 0  | list_1       | iface0    |
| 1  | list_4       | iface1    |
```

The expected result:

```
0 list_1 iface0 bla bla bla 
1 list_2        bla bla bla
2 list_3        bla bla bla 
3 list_4 iface1 bla bla bla
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
    ON t1.access_list = t2.access_list
```

When you need all the data from one table, and only the data that matches from another table, an `OUTER JOIN` is usually the way to go.  `LEFT JOIN` is actually short for `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, and specifies which table (the one on the left of the `JOIN` statement) will have all the data returned.  You can always use a `RIGHT JOIN` and name the tables the other way round (i.e. `table1 LEFT JOIN table2` is equivalent to `table2 RIGHT JOIN table1`), but the `LEFT JOIN` syntax is much more common.

A join that only returns matching data from both tables is known as an `INNER JOIN`, usually abbreviated to just `JOIN`.

Comment: I suggest you add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers may be good enough, but code+explanation answers are always better

Comment: @Barranka - A good point, well made.  I've edited in some more detail.